# tf.math.add() with keras plot_model() cound not show the two inputs of the add operation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model, tensorflow2.0

if I add one line to the model, such as     `p3 = tf.math.add(up_sample,x3_,name="up_sample + x3_")`
in the keras plot_model, it just shows the first input,as the following image shows

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I want to know how to show two inputs of the add() function with tensorflow2
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjJ9o.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the `tf.math.add` in a `Lambda` layer:

```
import tensorflow as tf

input1 = tf.keras.layers.Input((2,))
input2 = tf.keras.layers.Input((2,))
output = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.add(x[0], x[1]), name='upsample')([input1, input2])

model = tf.keras.Model([input1, input2], output)
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. this works for me. `p3 = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.add(x[0], x[1]), name='up_sample_Add_x3_')([up_sample,x3_])`